# Type-checking in template function returning given type

Tags: c++, templates

In a function like the following:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T foo () {
  std::string str("foo");
  if (typeid(T) == typeid(int)) return (T)(1); // Cast to T is required in order to make sure the function returns T
  else if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string)) return (T)str; 
  // ..
}
```

It will get a compile error because the compiler will go ahead and test all possible values of T on every single line, and there is no conversion from std::string to int, even though I already did a type-check.
How should I approach this problem?

Comment: You should approach this problem by updating your compiler to the C++17 standard, using `if constexpr`. If you can't do that, then use specialization.

Comment: If you decide to use `if constexpr` (which you should), replace `typeid(...) == typeid(...)` with `std::is_same_v<..., ...>`, because the condition is required to be `constexpr` and the `typeid`-based one is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++17 and later, you can use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) with [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```cpp
template <typename T>
T foo ()
{
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
    return 1;
  else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
    return "foo";
  // ..
}
```

This allows the compiler to optimize the `if`s at compile-time and eliminate any unused branches from evaluation.  For instance, when `T` is `int` then `foo<int>()` will simply be:

```cpp
int foo ()
{
  return 1;
}
```

And when `T` is `std::string` then `foo<std::string>()` will simply be:

```cpp
std::string foo ()
{
  return "foo";
}
```

Prior to C++17, you have to use template specialization instead to accomplish something similar, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T foo ()
{
  return T();
}

template<>
int foo<int> ()
{
  return 1;
}

template<>
std::string foo<std::string> ()
{
  return "foo";
}
```

Alternatively, use the specialization on a helper function/struct, especially if `foo()` has other code that is invoked regardless of the type of `T`, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T someValue()
{
  return T();
}

template<>
int someValue<int>()
{
  return 1;
}

template<>
std::string someValue<std::string>()
{
  return "foo";
}

template <typename T>
T foo ()
{
  ...
  return someValue<T>();
}
```

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct someType
{
    static const T value = T();
}

template<>
struct someType<int>
{
    static const int value = 1;
}

template<>
struct someType<std::string>
{
    static const std::string value = "foo";
}

template <typename T>
T foo ()
{
  ...
  return someType<T>::value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if constexpr`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T foo () {
  std::string str("foo");
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) return (T)(1); // Cast to T is required in order to make sure the function returns T
  else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) return (T)str; 
  // ..
}
```

This compiles the inner block only if the constant expression in its argument evaluates to a value considered `true`. The syntax needs to be correct in the inner block, though. The `is_same_v` checks if the types are the same.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, right, `typeid::operator==` is not `constexpr`. I'll fix it by replacing the way you check types.

Comment: In this example of `if constexpr`, you don't actually need the type-casts on the `return` statements. Inside a branch that `if constexpr` has not eliminated, the compiler knows the exact type of `T` and so things like `return 1` and `return str` will work just fine regardless of what was in the other branches (see: https://onlinegdb.com/rkrLine_w)